# HTML & CSS Table formatting issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table with html and using css to style it. I want it to be 8 rows and one column, but the rows are weirdly formatted, and the column only covers one piece of the table *see ss*

HTML:

```
<section class="table-body">
    <div class="table">
    <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Skills</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HTML & CSS</td>
    <td>MySQL</td> 
    <td>White Box Testing</td>
    <td>Black Box Testing</td>
    <td>Computer Networking</td>
    <td>Corporate Cybersecurity Best Practices</td> 
    <td>Python</td>
    <td>Software Engineering</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.table th, td{
    border: 1px solid;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(images/footer.jpeg);

}
```

I tried using some of the code from W3, and played around with the <td> and <th> but the "Skills" column will not cover the entire table.

This is how I was expecting it to look.

```
                            Skills
```

Cell 1   | Cell 2   |Cell 3   | Cell 4| Cell 5   | Cell 6 | Cell 7   | Cell 7|

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use the [colspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) attribute.

```html
<section class="table-body">
    <div class="table">
    <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="8">Skills</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HTML & CSS</td>
    <td>MySQL</td> 
    <td>White Box Testing</td>
    <td>Black Box Testing</td>
    <td>Computer Networking</td>
    <td>Corporate Cybersecurity Best Practices</td> 
    <td>Python</td>
    <td>Software Engineering</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</section>
```

In your case, `colSpan="8"` so it spans 8 columns